Automatically removing unused "theorem" environments in LaTeX documents
As a copy-editor, my job involves preparing the final formatting of scientific documents written directly in LaTeX, which I receive at the end of the peer-reviewing process.
Often, authors send us "dirty" papers, especially in the preamble, likely because they recycle code from previous papers. My goal is to develop tools (in Emacs Lisp) to automatically clean the preamble of all unused code.
Specifically, I am trying to remove the definitions of unused theorem environments within the paper.
For example, I recently encountered a paper with the following code in the preamble:
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{add}{Addendum}
\newtheorem{fact}{Fact}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

However, only the "example" environment is used in the paper. Here is a minimal working example (MWE):
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{add}{Addendum}
\newtheorem{fact}{Fact}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{example}
Example here.
\end{example}

\end{document}

My Elisp function searches the document for \begin{ENV} and if it does not find this string, it comments out \newtheorem{ENV} in the preamble. However, in this case, it fails because it also comments out:
%% \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

which sets the counter "theorem" used by the "example" environment.
I considered checking the .aux file for strings like:
\newlabel{example}{{B.1}{28}{}{theorem.B.1}{}}

Would this be sufficient, or should I expect other complications?

why do you want to do this at all?  You could move the entire preamble into duck.sty  and then add \usepackage{duck} then worrying about an unused definition in duck.sty is the same as worrying about an unused declaration in amsmath or amssymb would you want a version of amssymb.sty that did not define  \curvearrowleft if the document doesn't use that????

@DavidCarlisle Yours is a very interesting observation.
The fact is that there are some author definitions that I need to delete, correct or expand because 1) they are not in line with the style of our journals (e.g. \newcommand{\ie}{\emph{i.e.}}); 2) because they interfere with parsers/tools (e.g. \necommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}), 3) because I can unexpectedly interfere (e.g. \def\l{\lamba}) with any corrections (of style) or with how LaTeX itself works. Having a clean but "explicit" preamble (obtained automatically through specific tools) makes this type of operation easier.

Not really convinced, but it's your toolchain so OK. Sometime last century I started a meme on comp,text with 'the answer to "can emacs" is always yes'  so you have hope:-)  Just hope you never get one of my documents that tend to look like  https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/xii/xii.tex

@DavidCarlisle I don't even want to try to imagine what that code means! :-)

it's a complete plain tex document, try it.

@DavidCarlisle :O (This is the first time in my life that I have compiled a file in plain TeX.)

If you find an environment is not used then do not just
remove the declaration
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

You then need to search for any declations using that counter (theorem here) and move the trailing option to the first of these
so change
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

to
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]

Then change every instance of [theorem] to [proposition].
As proposition isn't used you would then iterate ending up with just the example environment,  being reset by section
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{example}
Example here.
\end{example}

\end{document}


I understand. This is definitely a solution that would return really clean code. I need to evaluate whether it's worth investing the time to implement it. In my case, taking the previous example, leaving \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] would still be an acceptable compromise.

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\NewCommandCopy{\stdnewtheorem}{\newtheorem}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_gabriele_thm_used_seq
\seq_new:N \g_gabriele_thm_unused_seq
\seq_new:N \g_gabriele_thm_defined_seq

\RenewDocumentCommand{\newtheorem}{m}
 {
  \AtBeginDocument
   {
    \AddToHookNext{env/#1/begin}{\seq_gput_right:Nn \g_gabriele_thm_used_seq {#1}}
   }
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_gabriele_thm_defined_seq {#1}
  \stdnewtheorem{#1}
 }
\AtEndDocument
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_gabriele_thm_defined_seq
   {
    \seq_if_in:NnF \g_gabriele_thm_used_seq { #1 }
     {
      \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_gabriele_thm_unused_seq { #1 }
     }
   }
  \seq_if_empty:NF \g_gabriele_thm_unused_seq
   {
    \iow_term:x { ***~Unused~theorems:^^J\seq_use:Nn \g_gabriele_thm_unused_seq {,~} }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{add}{Addendum}
\newtheorem{fact}{Fact}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{example}
Example here.
\end{example}

\end{document}

This will print on the console
*** Unused theorems:
axiom, theorem, proposition, lemma, corollary, claim, conjecture, add, fact, de
finition, remark, assumption

However, this would fail if the author writes something like
\newtheorem{exampleinner}{Example}
\newenvironment{example}{\exampleinner}{<somethingattheend>\endexampleinner}

and uses example. Here <somethingattheend> might be code to automatically add a QED symbol. You'd get exampleinner reported as unused, but it actually could have been used.
The standard strategy I used in order to find unused commands and environments is to comment everything out and run LaTeX. The error messages will show what can be removed safely.

Thank you. I haven't tested your code yet but I understand that if I deleted (commented out) the definitions, based on the .log, in this specific case the definition of "theorem" would also be deleted and therefore I would have to modify the definition of example. For me, however, it might be acceptable to leave the definition of "theorem" given in the preamble because my goal is to obtain clean but not "impeccable" code (and all with the minimum investment of formatting time possible).
